# How to Restrict other FTP user to create file/directory with a specific name on a server

Tags: server, permissions, users, ftp, user-management

I want to **add restriction on FTP users to create Files or Directories with a specific name** like "abcd" on my server. Only I would be able to create that specific file name. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Not without modifying the source of `ftpd`.

Comment: source will be same. The thing is nobody can't create file with "abcd" as file name.